# Average $lcm(a,b)$, $ 1\le a \le b \le n$, and asymptotic behavior

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, average, gcd-and-lcm

> What is the average value for $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$, with $ 1\le a \le b \le n$, for a
>   given $n$, and what is the asymptotic behavior? The $\mathrm{lcm}$ is the least common multiple.

I have calculated, as $(n, avg)$:

$$(10, 19.836)$$
$$(100, 1826.859)$$
$$(1000, 182828.976)$$

The values appear to converge quadratically to some constant.

This generalizes to $$\sum_{1 \le j \le k \le n} \mathrm{lcm}(j,k)$$

Comment: Only to write it other way, you try to determine the asypmtotic behaviour of $$\frac2{n(n+1)}\sum_{1\le j\le k\le n}\text{lcm}(j,k)$$, right?

Comment: @ajotatxe That is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a back-of-the-envelope calculation.
Start with the average value of $ab$, which is $(n+1)^2/4$.
Consider powers of $2$ only.  Three-quarters of the $(a,b)$ pairs lack $2$ as a common factor.  3/16 have $2^1$ as  a common factor, $3/64$ have $4$ as a common factor and so on.  So, on average, dealing with powers of $2$ reduces the average by a factor $$\frac341+\frac3{16}\frac12+\frac3{64}\frac14+...\\
=\frac34\left[1+\frac18+\frac1{64}+...\right]\\=\frac{3/4}{7/8}=6/7$$
Consider powers of $3$ only, which will be independent from powers of $2$.  The reduction is 
$$\frac891+\frac8{81}\frac13+\frac8{729}\frac19+...=\frac{8/9}{26/27}=\frac{12}{13}$$
For any prime $p$, the factor is $\frac{p^3-p}{p^3-1}$, so my final answer is 
$$\frac{(n+1)^2}4\prod_{p\,\text{prime}}\frac{p^3-p}{p^3-1}=\frac{(n+1)^2}4\frac{\zeta(3)}{\zeta(2)}$$
That is the Riemann $\zeta$ function, and the constant ratio is 
$$\frac{\zeta(3)}{4\zeta(2)}=0.18269074235...$$

Comment: Can you please explain why we sum up the probabilities that a pair has a factor of a power of $2$ divided by that power of 2?

Comment: This is why it is just back-of-the-envelope.  The subsets are each spread evenly through $[1,n]\times[1,n]$, so I suppose they each have the same average to start with.  Then a common factor of $2^k$ reduces the $lcm$ for each $(a,b)$ in that subset by $2^k$.

Answer (score 3):

[Theorem 6.3](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL10/Bordelles2/bordelles61.pdf) of Olivier Bordelles, Mean values of generalized gcd-sum and lcm-sum functions, Journal of Integer Sequences, Vol. 10 (2007), Article 07.9.2, says, for any real number $x$ sufficiently large, $$\sum_{n\le x}\sum_{j=1}^n[n,j]={\zeta(3)\over8\zeta(2)}x^4+O\bigl(x^3(\log x)^{2/3}(\log\log x)^{4/3}\bigr)$$